# vectors in different dimentional space

Tags: linear-algebra

Are the vector **U** = (1,2) and **V** = (1,2,0) the same vector? I think that both of them can be expressed the same geometrically.

Answer (score 0):

No, they are different. They live in different vector spaces. That's enough to tell us they are different.